# mod_rewrite redirects don’t work as expected

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two problems actually:

First, I’m trying to redirect several short URLs to a single page with more actions, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/login?$ ^login.php?action=login&next=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/reset?$ ^login.php?action=reset&next=$1 [L]
```

This is being written in the .conf file inside `<Directory>`. The problem is that the first rule gets executed, while the second doesn’t and I can’t figure why.

I also tried writing them like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login$
RewriteRule ^login.php?action=login&next=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /reset$
RewriteRule ^login.php?action=reset&next=$1 [L]
```

I should probably mention that `login.php` does not reside in the root directory, but in different subdirectories.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

The second issue I have is that if I put an `.htaccess` file inside the root directory, the rules in the .conf file don’t get executed anymore.

Inside the .conf file I have these rules:

```
<Directory>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
</Directory>
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is `login.php` located? If you have control over Apache `.conf` file then you don't need .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava in different directories of the root directory. Like, `www.site.com/subdir1/login.php` or `www.site.com/subdir2/login.php`.

Comment: Well rules need to point a **specific location**. You cannot keep a file in multiple places and hope it will be found on its own.

Comment: The thing is,  the rule `^/login?$ ^login.php?action=login&next=$1` works without problems. It is the other one that it doesn’t — `^/reset?$ ^login.php?action=reset&next=$1 [L]`.

Comment: Yes I know why it works. It is writing to `login.php` due to `MultiViews` but if your check `$_GET` content inside `login.php` then you may not get query parameters.

Comment: @anubhava, why is that?

Comment: For example: https://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/archives/2005/04/beware-of-apaches-multiviews/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161810/discussion-between-alex-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to extend on from my comments above. Place these rules in your site root .htaccess or in `httpd.conf` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?login(?:/(.*))?$ subdir1/login.php?action=login&next=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?reset(?:/(.*))?$ subdir1/login.php?action=reset&next=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.